# communication between two android app, one is publisher and other subscriber

Tags: android

I thought of working on content provider but I'm not sure weather i can access the inbuilt services like camera,gyroscope etc, using content provider
Any idea how to publish the services available on mobile phone and how to use that services from another app

Answer (score 0):

If it is to communicate between two applications, use the other side of the service, may need an [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).

If access to the data, it is through the [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

Comment: Can I Use AIDL for communication of two devices like one device act as publisher and other requester.

Comment: Yes,you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve interprocess data communication between two apps you can have a **SharedUserId** between the two apps. 
Check this link out 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WqMHehWI98&index=3&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hmkEaYIvLLm5IEGM0kpwU